# Is it possible to use Java to create dll?

Tags: java, dll

Want to create animation dll for Window XP
Is it ok to create Java2d animation and export as dll??

Comment: Why the downvote? I think this question is fairly straightforward.

Comment: I would guess, and I emphasize guess, that the dv came from someone wishing that the question was more specific about higher level goals of the OP. Personally, I think that in this case a comment would have sufficed, but tastes vary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. You need to write code in C++ to start the JVM with the invocation interface to JNI, and call into it. However, you may find it difficult to create windows in this way that integrate seamlessly with your Windows environment application to display your animation. This is a rather advanced JNI usage, and I'd recommend reading the JNI book before even trying a little bit of it.

Comment: While technically correct, it's really not a good idea(mildly put) to use Java for the job described in the question above.

Comment: True. There would have to be an awfully special reason. Just preferring to code in java2d versus native wouldn't do it.

Comment: In my case, I might try that, because there's just nothing like JavaFX. Qt has deprecated code, many macros, and so much unnecessary stuff, while every other c++ ui library with the same capabilities is basically a HTML layout engine which uses the quirky HTML standard....

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure you can only create .Jar files from java not dlls

Comment: One of us is answering the question he means to ask, but I have no idea which one of us :-)

Comment: I am pretty sure its you +1 for the answer :)

Comment: @bmargulies: +1 for you too :P

Comment: Well technically I did answer his question, but you provided a solution to what he is looking for which in my eyes is better than mine!

Comment: @both of you: I fear that the OP expected a magic bean that would grow into a DLL from Java code without having to write C++, so in some I'm going to return the favors.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt so, unless there's some 3rd party tools out there. For your case where graphics is involved, chances are even lower.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, what Quentin said should work.  
When you compile java to native with `GCJ` you first compile the `.java` files into platform specific `.o` (object) files.  Presumably you would compile the `.o` files into a `dll` rather than an `exe`.  `GCJ` also includes components like the garbage collector, and base java libraries.  None of which require a `JVM` to run.  The downer is that the `dll` would be huge.  A simple "Hello World" app when compiled with `GCJ` is `~35MB`, thanks to all the default libs and the garbage collector.  Likewise your `dll` would be huge.

Answer (score 1):

No, IIRC you can't. DLLs are linked directly when loaded. Java code needs a jvm, so you can only provide a dll that starts a jvm and starts code there, but not all necessarily stuff fits in the dll.

You should not do this. It looks like you're trying to use the wrong approach for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are "bridges" that allow Java and non-Java code to call into one another.  Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, these might be useful as you could write your Java code and then call into it from a C++ or C# DLL, depending on which language you are creating your DLL with, which will also determine what kind of bridge you need.  I have never seen a freely provided bridge though.  All the ones I've found when looking had to be purchased.

Answer (score 1):

Well…

1. [GCJ is available for Windows](http://rmathew.com/articles/gcj/bldgcj.html).
2. GCJ is part of GCC.
3. [GCC can create dlls](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html).

It might be possible to put that together to build DLLs using GCJ.

Comment: But GCJ still produces class files right? And that means they need a JVM

Comment: according to http://www.autexier.de/jmau/dev/gcj.html gcj still produces class files

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to generate DLLs from Java source code.

2 Methods I have used:

1. IKVM
2. Graal

IKVM is mature, but rather slow in runtime execution of the generated DLL.

Graal is fast, but early days and immature in the Windows environment. 
See https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/295 for further info.

There are other commercial options available as well.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with bmargulies. It's probably feasible for an expert, but it would be a large DLL and you'd be mixing technologies that were never made to work together. It doesn't make sense to try this, in my opinion.