# converting jar to native dll

Tags: dll, jar

This is my first post here. Please let me know if am doing wrong in posting.
 Well coming to the question, I have a jar(bundled collection of jars into one) and this jar doesnt have a main method. I have to convert this jar to dll and write a C code using that dll. (Native language bindings). So, are there any good tools to convert jar to native dll? I was googling and came across ikvmc but this converts jar to .Net dll. What is the difference between a normal dll and .Net dll? Can i use ikvmc to do my work? Or are there any other tools which converts jar to native dll? I see many tools that can covert jar to exe but not jar to dll. Please help me.Thanks..

Comment: Similar question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771005/is-it-possible-to-use-java-to-create-dll

Answer (score 0):

Look at instantiating a JVM in C and then wrap that code in a new DLL as required.

[How to call Java functions from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819536/how-to-call-java-function-from-c)